# Box Collision code

Tags: c++, collision

My box collision code is not working.

```
bool checkCollide(int x, int y, int oWidth, int oHeight, int xTwo, int yTwo, int oTwoWidth, int oTwoHeight)
{
   if (xTwo + oTwoWidth < x) 
      return false;  // box 2 is left of box 1

   if (x + oWidth < xTwo)
      return false;  // box 1 is left of box 2

   if (xTwo > x + oWidth) 
      return false;  // box 2 is right of box 1

   if (x > xTwo + oTwoWidth)
      return false;  // box 1 is right of box 2


   if (yTwo + oTwoHeight < y) 
      return false;  // box 2 is up of box 1

   if (y + oHeight < yTwo)
      return false;  // box 1 is up of box 2

   if (yTwo > y + oHeight) 
      return false;  // box 2 is down of box 1

   if (y > yTwo + oTwoHeight)
      return false;  // box 1 is down of box 2

   return true;
}
```

On of my boxes is clearly going over the other, however nothing is happening.
It seems to be returning false for some reason. I'm checking if one "rectangle" is out of bounds of the other, and if it isn't return true. Why isn't it working?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but `xTwo + oTwoWidth < x` and `x > xTwo + oTwoWidth` are the same (the same is true for `y > ...`

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't working, but you appear to have a lot of repetition in your code. As far as I can tell, "box 1 is left of box 2" is identical to "box 2 is right of box 1", "box 2 is left of box 1" is identical to "box 1 is right of box 2", and so on.

Comment: You sure use some strange variable names.  To each his own, but for me that's very hard to read.

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand what each variable actually represents based on the names you've used.

Comment: @Trying: As a general pointer to debugging code like this, place your objects in a static position. Note down which conditions should hold and which shouldn't. And then step through your code with a debugger to see if this is the case. Repeat for several cases to get an idea what (if anything) goes wrong.

Comment: -1 There must be a gazillion posts that deal with bbox collision.

Comment: A simple failing test case would have been instrumental at debugging this.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I would have done it (I would have provided an AABB object instead trough)

```
bool checkCollide(int x, int y, int oWidth, int oHeight, int xTwo, int yTwo, int oTwoWidth, int oTwoHeight)
{
    // AABB 1
    int x1Min = x;
    int x1Max = x+oWidth;
    int y1Max = y+oHeight;
    int y1Min = y;

    // AABB 2
    int x2Min = xTwo;
    int x2Max = xTwo+oTwoWidth;
    int y2Max = yTwo+oTwoHeight;
    int y2Min = yTwo;

    // Collision tests
    if( x1Max < x2Min || x1Min > x2Max ) return false;
    if( y1Max < y2Min || y1Min > y2Max ) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Indeed you can replace the x1Max etc directly with the values instead of using temporary variables. I added them for readability.

```
bool checkCollide(int x, int y, int oWidth, int oHeight, int xTwo, int yTwo, int oTwoWidth, int oTwoHeight)
{
    if( x+oWidth < xTwo || x > xTwo+oTwoWidth ) return false;
    if( y+oHeight < yTwo || y > yTwo+oTwoHeight ) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Note that this function does work with 2D boxes only, but it only require one more test line with z axis to be 3D compatible.

### ----------

Now let see your code with some comments on it

```
bool checkCollide(int x, int y, int oWidth, int oHeight, int xTwo, int yTwo, int oTwoWidth, int oTwoHeight)
{
   if (xTwo + oTwoWidth < x)    //(1) if( x2Max < x1Min )
      return false;

   if (x + oWidth < xTwo)       //(2) if( x1Max < x2Min )
      return false;

   if (xTwo > x + oWidth)       //(3) if( x2Min > x1Max ) ==> if( x1Max < x2Min ) ==> (2)
      return false;

   if (x > xTwo + oTwoWidth)    //(4) if( x1Min > x2Max ) ==> if( x2Max < x1Min ) ==> (1)
      return false; 


   if (yTwo + oTwoHeight < y)   //(5) if( y2Max < y1Min )
      return false;

   if (y + oHeight < yTwo)      //(6) if( y1Max < y2Min )
      return false;

   if (yTwo > y + oHeight)      //(7) if( y2Min > y1Max ) ==> if( y1Max < y2Min ) ==> (6)
      return false;

   if (y > yTwo + oTwoHeight)   //(8) if( y1Min > y2Max ) ==> if( y2Max < y1Min ) ==> (5)
      return false;

   return true;
}
```

So as you can see, half the tests are not required.
Considering the X axis, you first test is the same as the fourth one; your second test is the same as the third one.

### ----------

However, I can't spot any reason why your function does not return true when the box are overlapping. It should work.

I tested with the following values

```
std::cout << checkCollide(5, 5, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3) << std::endl; // false no collision
std::cout << checkCollide(5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3) << std::endl; // true collision
```

And it return false, and true as expected.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it should be width (or height) minus one.

Comment: This answer should be selected as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
bool checkCollide(int x1, int y1, int w1, int h1, int x2, int y2, int w2, int h2) {
  if (y1 + h1 < y2
     || y1 > y2 + h2
     || x1 + w1 < x2
     || x1 > x2 + w2) return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it should be width (or height) minus one.